# ¿Puedo cambiar el estilo ENTRY en xamarin?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xaml, xamarin.android

Buen día, Quiero saber si es posible darle estilos al campo ENTRY de Xamarin.Form, lo único que puedo hacer por css o Setter  es cambiar el color de fondo y el color de texto. Agradezco la ayuda o donde puedo investigar.

Answer (score -1):

claro que es posible, te dejo un tutorial: https://github.com/HoussemDellai/CustomEntryRenderer-XamarinForms

Comment: Te invito a realizar el [tour] para que conozcas el funcionamiento del sitio. Gracias por tomar el tiempo para responder, pero solo colocar un enlace es tomado como baja calidad. Por favor revisa [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) para que edites tu respuesta y se adapte mejor a la comunidad.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Aunque teoricamente este enlace conteste la pregunta, es preferible que incluyas las partes esenciales del mismo en la respuesta. Los enlaces pueden caducar y desaparecer. Ademas llevar al usuario a que lea en otro lugar la respuesta, no es la mejor opción.